# Regex: Capture text between 2 quotes and create new string

Tags: regex, capture

I have the following string

```
 { language: 'da', region: 'DK' },
```

I want to convert this to

```
grunt get-screenshot:da:DK
```

Caputuring the text between quotes is easy

```
 '([a-z]{2})'
```

but how can I get it so that second one is considered as a new match. I can assume the format holds always i.e. text between quotes is exactly of 2 chars length and the first has , after '

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
var s = "{ language: 'da', region: 'DK' },";
var m = s.match(/'(\w\w)',.*?'(\w\w)'/);
var cmd = "grunt get-screenshot:" + m[1] + ":" + m[2];
```

This result of the match `m` is the array:

```
["'da', region: 'DK'", "da", "DK"]
```